# Как найти проиндексированную ajax-страницу?

Tags: ajax, seo, яндекс-поиск

Сегодня с утра увидел, что яндекс проиндексировал страницу вида `site.ru/?_escaped_fragment_=chairs-for-kids/c11s3`. После недолгих скитаний по яндексу я узнал, что это ajax-страница. Так вот вопрос, как найти эту страницу? Сколько искал - не нашел. Хоть и на сайте используется в некоторых местах ajax, но именно этой нет. И второй вопрос. Т.к. страница выводит главную страницу, будет ли яндекс считать ее дублем главной?

Comment: главная страница проиндексированна?

Comment: Да, главная страница проиндексирована. Как оказалось до меня домен был занят каким-то сайтом на wix. Вот яндекс почему-то их и показывал в поиске. Что плохо, они считаются дублями. Пришлось удалять их в robots.txt и в вебмастер панели яндекса. В гугл такой проблемы не наблюдается.